# Need a formula that will set my rows green based on the value recorded in the 'L' column

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, rows

I have an Excel Spreadsheet where I have a number of rows. I want rows (entire row) to be colour coded based on whether column 'L' is Keep, Delete, or Pending.

Comment: You'll need VBA (programming within Excel) for this, it can't be done using conditional formatting (at least that I know of).

Comment: @Dominique, it's possible.

Comment: You need to learn more about Excel's [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f), there are also thousands of tutorials for that in the Internet. This is for sure no programming question, and therefore I'm voting for this question to be closed. [Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)]

Comment: I've seen other Excel questions posed on here, very sorry. My job doesn't require programming. I've tried to look online but I can't see anything that solves my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please select entire sheet, clear any CF rules from it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR($L1="Keep",$L1="Delete",$L1="Pending")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to highlight an entire row if its value in column L meets your criteria, here's how you can do it:

**1.** Select the entire sheet. You could do this by pressing `CONTROL + A` twice.

**2.** Create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula:

```
=$L1="Keep"
```

**3.** Set the needed formats relative to this.

**4.** Repeat for the "Delete" and "Pending" values.

Comment: for clarification: it needs to verify the value from column L through out the whole column instead of just one cell

Comment: I can't seem to picture what you wish to do here. I thought, for example, you wanted to highlight row 2 if L2 has the text value Keep, Delete or Pending. Could you explain through an example.